# Microsoft Azure - unable to create "Team Project" using free trail account

Tags: azure, tfs

I am new to azure and i am trying to create a *team project* on portal.azure.com and its failing with below error.

The resource group is getting created but team project creation fails

```
Error: 
    {"Code":"InvalidRequestValue","Message":"TF400902: There was a failure executing the job. Job Id for the failed creation:b055035e-1b17-480d-a577-abce5d9aff75","Target":"GetProjectJobStatus"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reproduce your issue successful with my azure account.

It is not related to the free trail account. If your steps are accurate. (Please refer this blog: [Create a VS Online Team Project from the new Azure Portal](http://www.almguide.com/2014/09/create-a-vs-online-team-project-from-the-new-azure-portal/))

This may coursed by azure. Suggest you try again after several hours.

---

**Update**

Even though with this error, I received a successful email from Azure. Please also check whether did you get this email.
[image]